# Vue rerendering on cookie value change

Tags: vue.js, cookies, jwt, render

I've been working on my first Vue project and had to figure out a way to keep the user's login "state" since the back-end is stateless (`jwt`). I've figured to keep this state in a cookie, which I store using the `vue-cookies` plugin. So i set it like so
`cookies.set("isUserLoggedIn", true, "infinite");`.
I then put it in a computed property, so the view of the application would be rerendered

```
  computed: {
    getUserLoginStatus() {
      return this.$cookies.get("isUserLoggedIn") != null;
    }
  }
```

which works, but only after a manual page refresh, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, cookies are not reactive. You can make them reactive though with the help of some lib like [that one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies-reactive). It's allowing you to use cookies as computed properties or to watch cookies for changes made by a request

Comment: Thank you, it's pretty much exactly what I was already using but allows for what I needed.